# Google search snippets show the Linked sidebar instead of more interesting content

Tags: discussion, google, linked-questions

I'm not sure whether this has come up before, but it looks odd to me:

> [image]

([Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=powershell+change+prompt), [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725888/windows-powershell-changing-the-command-prompt).)

It's nice to see Stack Exchange on the little snippet thing on Google, but are the contents of the Linked sidebar the best thing to have there? I obviously know that this is not something SE can fix directly, but it seemed relevant so I thought I'd bring it up, so perhaps e.g. the team can have a word with the google snippetting team to try and make that a bit more useful for folks doing searches.

Comment: Very related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295122/stack-exchange-communities-are-different-how-speech-bubbles/295123

Comment: I'm on mobile so I don't see the linked sidebar, but I'm wondering if the linked question scores happened to be 1, 2, 3, and 4 and were misinterpreted as a list of steps.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom [Nope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD1k6.png), it reads 4, 0, 0, 1 at the moment.